# Are there any weapons that have the heavy property, but not the Two-handed property?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Are there any weapons that have the heavy property, but not the Two-handed property? I am looking for something that my Bladesinger wizard can use Great Weapon master with.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 13):

#### No.

A brief survey of the equipment tables found in chapter 5 of the *Player’s Handbook* shows no mundane weapons which have the heavy property but lack the two handed property. This observation is confirmed in the *Sage Advice Compendium* in a [question about the Dual Wielder feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#DualWielder):

> Every heavy weapon in the Player’s Handbook also has the two-handed property.

Further, there are no magic items that fit either, though a more thorough investigation is required to independently verify this.

And this makes sense. The reason two handed weapons require two hands is typically their weight (though the double bladed scimitar is an exception). We should expect any weapon heavy enough to get the heavy property to be heavy enough to require two hands. It also makes sense from a balance perspective - as Tiger Guy pointed out in a comment, a one-handed heavy weapon would allow the use of GWM with a shield, which would be an exceptionally strong combo.

Comment: In real life there is chinese swordbreaker, that looks like a jian sword but the "blade" cross section is square, keeping the same width as the sword's width. It is one handed and not for your average strength fighter. So there are real word weapons that *should* be one handed and heavy if they will ever appear in the rules. It just so happens they didn't.

Comment: This is a balance mechanic I assume to prevent sword and board from Great Weapon Master

Comment: @Molot I think you're overestimating the weight of a chinese swordbreaker. Even the heaviest one-handed models we know of today weigh under 3 kilos, which is comparable to a medieval mace, and a lot of the heavier ones are more recent, after they become ceremonial weapons-of-office of high ranking police officials (much like the japanese jitte, which is very similar). A mace doesn't require extraordinary strength to handle; it shouldn't be that different.

Comment: In terms of the strength and endurance required to wield them, the “heaviest” weapons are all one-handed—because having both arms involved allows vastly superior balance and control, and allows more of your back and chest muscles to come into play, well more than doubling how much of your strength applies. Plus two-handed weapons are held close to the body, while many one-handed weapons are held at extension, which is **much** more work. In reality, the weapon in Ch. 5 that requires the most strength is probably the rapier: that is a _long_ piece of steel to hold one-handed at arm’s length.

Comment: So rather than “makes sense,” it would be better to say that it’s internally consistent, and consistent with most fantasy narratives. Those narratives just don’t hold up very well compared to reality. Realistically, many one-handed weapons deserve the heavy tag, more so than many two-handed weapons. But it would be a problem for the game rules, most likely, if the rapier was both heavy and finesse.